# Running bash using posix instead of fork/execv

Tags: c, linux, posix, ipc

I have a CLI, one of the commands is entering into Linux bash shell.
This is the code which does it using fork & execv:

```
if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    syslog_debug(LOG_ERR, "Could not fork");
}
if (pid == 0) {
    /* In child, open the child's side of the tty.  */
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= maxfd; i++)
    {   
        close(i);
    }       
    /* make new process group */
    setsid();
    if ((fd[0] = open(tty_name, O_RDWR /*| O_NOCTTY*/)) < 0) {
        syslog_debug(LOG_ERR, "Could not open tty");
        exit(1);
    }
    fd[1] = dup(0);
    fd[2] = dup(0);
    /* exec shell, with correct argv and env */
    execv("/bin/sh", (char *const *)argv_init);
    exit(1);
}
```

I want to replace the fork/execv and to use posix_spawn instead:

```
ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_init(&action);
pipe(fd);
for(i = 0; i <= maxfd; i++)
{   
   ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose (&action, i);
}    
ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2 (&action, fd[1], 0);
ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2 (&action, fd[2], 0); 
ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_addopen (&action, STDOUT_FILENO, tty_name, O_RDWR, 0);
char* argv[] = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "bash", NULL };
int status;
extern char **environ;
posix_spawnattr_t attr = { 0 };

snprintf( cmd, sizeof(cmd), "bash");
status = posix_spawn( &pid,
                    argv[0],
                    action /*__file_actions*/,
                    &attr,
                    argv,
                    environ );
posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy(&action);
```

But it doesn't work.
Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at what the code in the original fork/exec does:

- close all file descriptors
- open the tty, which will coincidentally get an fd of `0`, i.e. it's stdin
- duplicate this fd twice (`dup(0)`), which puts them into stdout and stderr
- exec the shell command

Your new code doesn't follow the same pattern at all. What you want to do is repeat the process, but be more explicit:

close all the FDs:

```
for(i = 0; i <= maxfd; i++)
{
   ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose (&action, i);
}
```

open the tty into `STDIN_FILENO`:

```
ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_addopen (&action, STDIN_FILENO, tty_name, O_RDWR, 0);
```

duplicate the `STDIN_FILENO` into `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO`:

```
ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2 (&action, STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO);
ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2 (&action, STDIN_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO);
```

Then the `posix_spawn` should take place in the correct context.

For the old fork/exec process, you should have done something like:

```
int fd = open(tty_name, O_RDWR /*| O_NOCTTY*/);
if (fd != STDIN_FILENO) dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
if (fd != STDOUT_FILENO) dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
if (fd != STDERR_FILENO) dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO);
```

It's more explicit in intent.

> The reason for the ifs is to prevent the accidental `dup2` of the original `fd` into the new fd number. The only one that really should have that problem is the first one because `fd` == `STDIN_FILENO` because you don't have any other file descriptors open at that point.

To combine this into a small piece of code, with `echo something` rather than an invocation of `bash` we have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <spawn.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void
do_spawn()
{
  int ret;
  posix_spawn_file_actions_t action;
  int i;
  pid_t pid;
  int maxfd = 1024;
  char *tty_name = ttyname (0);

  ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_init (&action);
  for (i = 0; i <= maxfd; i++) {
      ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose (&action, i);
  }
  ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_addopen (&action, STDIN_FILENO, tty_name, O_RDWR, 0);
  ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2 (&action, STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO);
  ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2 (&action, STDIN_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO);
  char *argv[] = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo something", NULL };
  int status;
  extern char **environ;
  posix_spawnattr_t attr = { 0 };

  posix_spawnattr_init(&attr);
  posix_spawnattr_setflags(&attr, POSIX_SPAWN_USEVFORK);
  status = posix_spawn(&pid, argv[0], &action /*__file_actions*/ , &attr, argv, environ);
  printf ("%d %ld\n", status, pid);

  wait (0);

  posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy (&action);

}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  do_spawn();
}
```

This needs to be compiled with `-D_GNU_SOURCE`, as otherwise `POSIX_SPAWN_USEVFORK` is not defined.

Comment: 'ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2 (&action, STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO);
ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2 (&action, STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO);' shouldn't the second be STDERR_FILENO instead of STDOUT_FILENO?

Comment: oops, typo, the second line should have been `STDERR_FILENO`, not `STDOUT_FILENO`

Comment: Thanks, It's clarify some issues. but, it's look i still have problem with posix_spawn().

Comment: I don't know why, but the above solution is working only incase I delete the 'for' loop of the 'posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose'. Incase the loop isn't deleted I see in the procees list: '[org_proc_name] <defunct>' and I don't see the bash prompt or the echo print.

Comment: My code there is using `ttyname(0)` to get the ttyname. If that doesn't work, then you'll not see the output from the command - that could be the issue (I don't know, I'm just making educated guesses here). the `<defunct>` may indicate a crash in the runner, triggered by `ttyname(0)` returning `NULL`. Unfortunately I don't know enough about your execution environment to make any other guesses.