# Calling setsid() at proc created by posix_spawn()

Tags: linux, posix, setsid

This question is follow-up for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890509/running-bash-using-posix-instead-of-fork-execv).

When the bash command is issued by `posix_spawn()` I get the message:

> bash: no job control in this shell

I think is because in the fork sequence there is call to the function `setsid()` and I don't know how to simulate this operation while using `posix_spawn()`.

Is there a way to make new session for the bash process?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It's not part of the current `posix_spawn` interface.
Adding it has been discussed at http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1044
and apparently at least one implementation (QNX) provides `POSIX_SPAWN_SETSID` as an extension, but to stay standard compliant you need to use `fork`.

Using `fork` shouldn't be an issue if the parent process is small, so I imagine that to get the best of both worlds, you could use `posix_spawn` to launch a small helper binary that `forks` and calls `setsid`.
IMO, using `setsid` should be rare enough for the small additional cost of double-execing to be negligible.